# c++11 Template Factory pattern and constructor with parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, factory

I'm trying to make a c++11 templated factory with automatic registration,
I pretty much followed this: http://www.drdobbs.com/conversations-abstract-factory-template/184403786

So I have a AFactory  like this:

```
template<class BaseType, typename IDKey = std::string>
class AFactory : public Singleton<AFactory<BaseType, IDKey>>
{
friend class Singleton<AFactory>;

private:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<BaseType>(*typeCreator)();

public:
    AFactory() = default;
    ~AFactory() = default;

    AFactory(const AFactory&) = delete;
    AFactory& operator=(const AFactory&) = delete;

    void registerNewClass(const IDKey& key, const typeCreator& creator)
    {
        _registerTypes.insert({key, creator});
    };

    template<typename... Args>
    std::unique_ptr<BaseType> create(const IDKey& key, Args&&... args) const
    {
        return (_registerTypes.at(key))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    };

private:
    std::unordered_map<IDKey, typeCreator> _registerTypes;
};
```

And a registration class like that:

```
template<class BaseType, class RealType, typename IDKey = std::string>
class AFactoryRegistration
{
public:
    AFactoryRegistration(const IDKey& key)
    {
        AFactory<BaseType>::instance().registerNewClass(key, &instancier);
    };

    ~AFactoryRegistration() = default;
    AFactoryRegistration(const AFactoryRegistration&) = delete;
    AFactoryRegistration& operator=(const AFactoryRegistration&) = delete;

    static std::unique_ptr<BaseType> instancier()
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<BaseType>(new RealType());
    };
};
```

But I still have a problem with classes which take construction parameters.
For example if I have a class:

```
class Point : public stuff
{
public:
Point(int x, int y);
/*...*/

};
```

How can I register the class Point to the factory taking the constructor Point(int x, int y) ?

Comment: I think the underlying problem is that you have to provide a common interface for type construction. This is expressed in the type of `typeCreator`: take no arguments and return a `unique_ptr<BaseType>`, i.e. construct an object from no arguments and return it as a pointer. If we follow this pattern, you have to allow (syntactically) construction of any type in the factory from two `int`s, if you want to allow it for one type.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do another way, I just wanted something that you can use like that:
AFactory<InterfaceClass>::instance().create("Implementation", constructor arguments);

Comment: You cannot check the types of the constructor arguments at compile-time with that pattern, if you allow different parameters for different constructed types. The factory is a way to decouple the constructed type from how you create it. Apart from the checking, implementing conversions from the arguments to the constructor's parameters will be close to impossible (since that requires a priori knowledge of both types). -- If all of your types can be constructed from, say, two `int`s, then you can write such a factory. But if one type needs an `int` but another needs a `string`, almostimpossible.

Comment: I'd like to find a solution where I got auto type registration and passing any argument to the constructor but I'm struggling to find how I can do that.

Comment: maybe this could help http://oopscenities.net/2014/02/01/c11-perfect-forwarding/

Comment: My problem is more, that I can't register multiple derived classes taking differrent constructor arguments.
The article implementation require the user to know the derived class type, which in sense defeat the usage of the factory, as I could as well had called the derived class constructor myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow. A four year old question. Maybe std::any would help. You can store anything in std::any.

The any_cast is a little bit tricky.

See below example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <any>


// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};



using UPTRB = std::unique_ptr<Base>;


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
UPTRB createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key, class Object>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, std::any> selector;
public:
    Factory() : selector() {}
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, std::any>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template<typename Function>
    void add(Key key, Function&& someFunction) { selector[key] = std::any(someFunction); };

    template <typename ... Args>
    Object create(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return std::any_cast<std::add_pointer_t<Object(Args ...)>>(selector[key])(args...);
        }
        else return nullptr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int, UPTRB> factory{
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>}
    };
    factory.add(3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>);


    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    UPTRB b1 = factory.create(1, 1, s1);
    UPTRB b2 = factory.create(2, 2, '2', 2L);
    UPTRB b3 = factory.create(3, 3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.create(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

You could generalize it even more. But then is just a wrapper around a creator function.

Comment: Thanks you!,  I thinks it was for a school project hopefully it was successful even without the fully automatic factory :)